# spring @transactional noRollbackFor unexpectedly rollsback...any clue?

Tags: spring, weblogic12c, transactional

I have following problem :
Servers runs on WL 12.
The main code is in a EAR, in methods with @Transactional explicitly written as NoRollbackFor=RuntimeException.class
When the exception occurs inside the EAR code, the noRollbackFor is correctly taken into account.
However, when the error occurs in a remote call to another WAR, the transaction is flagged as setRollbackOnly, and subsequent calls to the dabatase (read operations) fail (even if the exception is trapped in the calling code).

Any idea as to why this happens / how to avoid this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your exception is of type RuntimeException, which triggers a rollback, but checked exception does not

Comment: That's the whole point. The Exception thrown in the WAR is a Runtime one. The service called (on the same machine) is probably @Transactional.
However, it marks as rolled back also the transaction in the EAR while this one is clearly flagged as noRollbackFor RuntimeException. (Further calls to hibernate reads lead to errors due to this).